# Selenide doesn't find the Web element

Tags: java, selenide

Could somebody help to understand what is wrong with element searching via Selenide.

I have such HTML code:

```
<div>
  Current method: 
  <strong>
    SMS
  </strong>
</div>
```

The Selenium finds the element throw this xpath

```
findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(. , \"Current method\")]/strong"))
```

but Selenide returns ElementNotFound exception with the same locator

```
$(By.xpath("//div[contains(. , \"Current method\")]/strong"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need strong, you can just

```
   $(By.xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'SMS')]"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can us following option.
$("strong:contains('SMS')"); `Using css selectors method`

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$(byText("Current method:")).shouldBe(Condition.exist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Selenium->
findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Current method')]/strong"));

Using Selenide->
$(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Current method')]/strong"));

These two method can be used in selenium as well as selenide.Methods are not specific to Selenium or selenide